# Probability of this event?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

A certain city receives three newspapers $A, B,$ and $C$. Newspaper $A$ has $50\%$ of the readers in that city, newspaper $B$ has $30\%$, and newspaper $20\%$. Assuming that no one reads more than one newspaper, what is the probability that among six randomly chosen people, three, two, and one respectively read newspapers $A, B,$ and $C$?

The answer key issued by the examination conducting agency shows the answer as $\dfrac{27}{200}$.

My attempt: It should be $\dfrac{\binom{100}{6}}{\binom{50}{3}\binom{30}{2}\binom{20}{1}}\neq\dfrac{27}{200}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things wrong.  first, your numerator and denominator are swapped.

Second, your attempt would have been correct if it were known that the city had *very specifically exactly* 100 people in it.  That is not necessarily the case here.  There are "*many*" people in a city typically.  When we talk about sampling for a "*large*" sample size like this, the usual thing we do is to sample with replacement.

As such, the intended answer is to use the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).

$$\binom{6}{3,2,1}0.5^3\cdot 0.3^2\cdot 0.2^1$$